Searching a specific word in urls containing specific characters in Google search
In Google search I wrote:
"albero" inurl:(unipi OR unina OR unimi OR unimib OR polimi OR unito OR polito OR uniroma1 OR uniroma2 OR uniroma 3 OR units OR unitn OR unibz OR uniba OR poliba OR unibas OR unifi OR unife OR unisa OR unica OR unicatt)

where albero is the word I want to find in the urls containing unipi OR unina OR unimi OR unimib OR etc.
Can you tell me what is the right query please? The above query partially "works", after 11 results it gives me urls not required (amazon, facebook, airbnb etc.).

Search Ignores Parentheses
# Your Search Query 

"albero" inurl:(unipi OR unina OR unimi
  OR unimib OR polimi OR unito OR polito
  OR uniroma1 OR uniroma2 OR uniroma3
  OR units OR unitn OR unibz OR uniba
  OR poliba OR unibas OR unifi OR unife
  OR unisa OR unica OR unicatt)
The search query above doesn't work as expected because Google Search ignores parentheses.
Interpretation
Your query above is equivalent to the following:
"albero" unina OR unimi OR unimib
  OR polimi OR unito OR polito
  OR uniroma1 OR uniroma2 OR uniroma3
  OR units OR unitn  OR unibz OR uniba
  OR poliba OR unibas OR unifi
  OR unife OR unisa OR unica OR unicatt
  OR inurl:unipi
Multiple inurl Terms
To avoid repeatedly adding inurl when searching multiple terms, use the operator allinurl which includes all terms that follow (until the next operator).
For example,
# Corrected Syntax 

"albero" allinurl: unipi OR unina OR unimi
  OR unimib OR polimi OR unito OR polito
  OR uniroma1 OR uniroma2 OR uniroma3 OR units
  OR unitn OR unibz OR uniba OR poliba OR unibas
  OR unifi OR unife OR unisa OR unica OR unicatt
If you are looking for your search term "albero" in page text only, you can add the search operator intext to further restrict the search:
intext:"albero" allinurl: unipi OR unina OR unimi
  OR unimib OR polimi OR unito OR polito
  OR uniroma1 OR uniroma2 OR uniroma3 OR units
  OR unitn OR unibz OR uniba OR poliba OR unibas
  OR unifi OR unife OR unisa OR unica OR unicatt
If you are unsure of Search syntax you can leverage Google Advanced Search  to build the query for you then review the URL it creates.

you stated use the operator **allinurl** which includes all terms that follow (until the next operator), does operator include double quote? Eg: In case of allinurl: A OR B "C", is allinurl group in effect until "B or until "C" ?

Further, since logical AND has higher precedence over OR, so sometimes we may use parentheses to clarify, eg: (A OR B) C. But allinurl ignores parentheses, then how can we do so?

@Grace Q: "does operator include double quote?" A: No it does not.

@Grace Your second comment has a bit more meat on the bone.  Comments are not the place to ask questions.  You should Ask a new Question so you can include enough detail that I and others can understand the problem and benefit from it.  The question should include everything necessary to answer it but if useful you can link back to this question for context.  Be sure to include an explanation of what you are trying to do and what is/isn't working.

I reached the goal by using this query even if sometimes there are not requested urls:
"albero" inurl:unipi OR inurl:unina OR inurl:unimi OR inurl:unimib OR inurl:polimi OR inurl:unito OR inurl:polito OR inurl:uniroma1 OR inurl:uniroma2 OR inurl:uniroma3 OR inurl:units OR inurl:unitn OR inurl:unibz OR inurl:uniba OR inurl:poliba OR inurl:unibas OR inurl:unifi OR inurl:unife OR inurl:unisa OR inurl:unica OR inurl:unicatt

